# Does JQuery really work in WebView?

Tags: jquery, android, webview

Somebody say can, but I don't see any example about JQuery in WebView. I tried many ways but no succeed.
This is a simple example code. The CSS works but JQuery doesn't.

**1) Internet permission was added.**

**2) Javascript was enabled.**

**3) Tested on emulator 1.6 and 2.2.**

```
public class UsingJQueryActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/js_please_run.html");
    }
}
```

"assets/js_please_run.html"

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script>
        alert('Hello world');
        confirm("Hello android");                       
    </script>
    <style>
    div {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        All I hear is raindrops.Falling on the rooftop. Oh baby tell me why you have to go. 
        Cause this pain I feel you won't go away. And today, I'm officially missing you.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebView` will by default not show dialogs as that is part of the UI, you'll have to test javascript in some other way or set a `WebChromeClient` that shows dialogs, see [`onJsAlert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsAlert%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsResult%29)

It is helpful to set a `WebChromeClient` like this one:

```
public class DebugWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private static final String TAG = "DebugWebChromeClient";

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage m) {
            Log.d(TAG, m.lineNumber() + ": " + m.message() + " - " + m.sourceId());

            return true;
    }

}
```